# Convert String to int16

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I faced a "ridiculous" problem.
I was trying to convert a string to int16 (I am forced to do it in int16 and not in int32/integer).
My first thought was to try:

```
convertedVal = Convert.ToInt16(newVal)
```

which thrown an exception: *Value was either too large or too small for UInt16.*
But my string was "10", so it was between the minValue and the maxValue.
I solved my problem using :

```
convertedVal = Int16.Parse(newVal) 'TryParse works also
```

Although I solved my problem I haven't understand what I did wrong.
Could somebody explain to me why this happened?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Just drop the `Convert` class, it’s a horrible construct that shouldn’t exist in the first place. Convert by using proper casts or the `XYZ.{Try}Parse` methods.

Comment: It is coming from an xml file. So the value is just a string:10 and I have to put it in one type int16.

Comment: I will definitely follow the Parse method since it gave the right result from the beginning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This usually happens if there is an extra space on the string, so better `Trim` it

```
convertedVal = Convert.ToInt16(newVal.Trim())
```

Comment: ALthough I didn't believe you, because my string value was just 10 without spaces (I verified that) your trick with the trim worked!!!
Do you know why?(Before trimming:?val
"10"
After trim:
?val
"10"

Comment: Very strange, could you test this `if newVal = newVal.Trim()`?

Comment: wow so weird, the code above is untested. when i tried to test this code `Dim x as String = "   10   "` then `Dim y As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(x)` still gives 10. I mean ther is no excpetion on it.

Comment: @bendataclear: I tested it and gives true. The funny thing is that delete the code and rewrite just convertedVal = Convert.ToInt16(newVal) and now works!!!. WITHOUT trim!!!So no problem at all. It is like never happened. I haven't touch the xml (the string value). So I believe that I need coffee and restart (the pc and myself)

Answer (score 2):

Both methods should be the same according to [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/basyfs27.aspx)

> Using the `ToInt16(String)` method is equivalent to passing value to the `Int16.Parse(String)` method. value is interpreted by using the formatting conventions of the current thread culture.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you get this string?
If it comes from user input I wouldn't trust much that he/she types a correct int16 value to use a Convert or Parse method.

using TryParse leads to a more robust code.

```
Dim result as Short
Dim newVal as String = "10 sadaas"
if Int16.TryParse(newVal, result) = False then
    result = 0
end if
```